# angularjs ng-repeat not updating view when new data comes in

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-ng-repeat

I have a service which will make a call to the server and returns the data. I am binding service to a variable on scope.

Example:

- Let the service be `DataModelService`
- in the controller : `$scope.data = DataModelService`
- in the view  `<div ng-repeat="value in data.persons">{{value.name}}</div>`

My Code :

```
This is how my code looks like:

/**DataModelService**/
factory('DataModelService', [
    'DataService',
    function (DataService) {
        var service;
        service = {
            changeState: function (params) {
                DataService.changePersonState(params)
                    .then(function (response) {
                        service.loadData(response.data);
                    });
            },
            loadData: function (responseData) {
                service.persons = responseData.persons;
            }
        }
        return service;
    }

]);
/**DataService**/
factory('DataService', ['$http',
    function ($http) {
        return {
            changePersonState: function (params) {
                return $http.post("url", params);
            }
        }
    }
]);


/**DataController**/
.controller('DataController', ['DataModelService',
    function (DataModelService) {
        $scope.data = DataModelService;
    }
]);
```

/**view**/

`<div ng-repeat = "person in data.persons" >{{person.name}} </div>`

On the view I am doing a ng-repeat on a key in data i.e. ng-repeat="value in data.persons"
and also I have an option to change the state of person to active or inactive, so whenver i make a change to the state of the person, a call is sent to the server and data is set into the Service and as it is binded to the view, it should automatically update the data. But whats happening in my case, ng-repeat is not removing old data and instead it is appending new data to the old data.

Comment: Please post related code. How can we solve with this minimal information?

Comment: are you sure the data from the server is as expected?

Comment: yes..for the first time its working fine, i.e. ng-repeat is showing the correct data, but whenever a new call is made and i get same data from server with updated state..its showing the previous data and also new data. I also printed the data in console, it has the correct data. The problem is old data is not getting replaced with new data even though persons has new data in it.

Answer (score 1):

For me its not good approach to write promise callback (`then`) into service. Because in your case,  `DataModelService` returns data with some delay but not promise. And we don't know when.

So the way to make it work to add basic `$timeout` and fetch data from service by using other method.

So my suggestion is <kbd>[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/645/)</kbd>

and your fixed example: <kbd>[Demo2](http://jsfiddle.net/9Ymvt/650/)</kbd>

If we will take your example, it should be like:

*JS*

```
var fessmodule = angular.module('myModule', ['ngResource']);

fessmodule.controller('fessCntrl', function ($scope, DataModelService, $timeout) {

    $scope.alertSwap = function () {       

        DataModelService.changeState('ff');

        $timeout(function(){
         $scope.data = DataModelService.getResponse();
        }, 10);       
    }

});

fessmodule.$inject = ['$scope', 'Data', '$timeout'];


/**DataModelService**/
fessmodule.factory('DataModelService', [ 'DataService',function (DataService) {
     var value = [];

    var service = {
        changeState: function (params) {

           DataService.changePersonState(params)
                .then(function (response) {                   
                   value = response.persons;                  
            });
        },
        getResponse : function(){
           return value;
        }
    }
    return service;
}

]);
/**DataService**/
fessmodule.factory('DataService', ['$q',function ($q) {
    var data = {        // dummy 
        persons: [{
            name: "Bob"
        }, {
            name: "Mark"
        }, {
            name: "Kelly"
        }]
    };

    var factory = {
        changePersonState: function (selectedSubject) {
            var deferred = $q.defer();
            deferred.resolve(data);
            return deferred.promise;
        }
    }

    return factory;

} //function
]);
```

Comment: Actually my datamodelservice calls a dataservice which will make calls to the server and returns a promise to datamodelservice, inside the service i am setting data into it.

Comment: I added Demo. BTW,  I show you the concept how to run `ng-repeat` on model `data.persons` that populates into `then` callback

Comment: @AnutejaMallampati I don't think its good aproach to impelemenet promise `then` into service

Comment: @AnutejaMallampati see my edit I posted, hope it help

Comment: But for the first time i am using resolve to make the UI wait until i get back the response from server, but once the UI is rendered and i make any changes to the state a call is sent to the server and updates the service. As service is binded to the view in controller, it should automatically update the view with new data but it is not happening instead it is showing both old data and new data, and whenver i make any change to state again the new data is being replaced but not old data which is rendered for the first time.

Comment: I also tried printing the data in browser console and it doesn't have old data in it when i change the state

Comment: Did you see Demo with fix?